# How to get for loop to complete

Tags: jquery, for-loop, dom, jquery-selectors, nodes

I have an object I am using to add tooltips on load after a splash screen is closed. The object looks something like this:

```
layerNameMapping =
{
    "samp_bldgs": {"title": "Sample_Bldgs", "index": 0, "tt": "Approximate center of buildings within BLE areas", "visible": false},
    "buildings": { "title": "Buildings", "index": 1, "tt": "Approximate center of buildings within BLE areas", "visible": true},
    "buildings_risk_chng": { "title": "Buildings Risk Change", "index": 2, "tt": "Color-coded change of building from effective flood hazard to BLE", "visible": false},
    "contours": { "title": "Contours", "index": 3, "tt": "2ft contour lines", "visible": false}, 
    "contours_diced": { "title": "Contours_Diced", "index": 4, "tt": "2ft contour lines", "visible": true}, 
    "modeled_streamline": { "title": "Modeled Streamline", "index": 5, "tt": "Modeled stream centerlines for BLE studies", "visible": true},
    "counties": { "title": "Counties", "index": 6, "tt": "County boundaries", "visible": true},
    ....
}
```

Basically the code, using `jQuery` to iterate through items in a `node selector` object, has a function (`tooltipper2`) to check each item against the `item.title` in the `layerNameMapping`. There will always be 4 items in the main node selector (the variable called `baseElement_map`) on load.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#myDisclaimerModal').modal('show'); 
    function tooltipper2(name) {
        var lyr_map = layerNameMapping;
        var size = Object.keys(lyr_map).length;
        tt = name;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (lyr_map[Object.keys(lyr_map)[i]].title === name) {
                tt = lyr_map[Object.keys(lyr_map)[i]].tt;
            }
        }
        return tt;
    }  
    $('#splash_close_btn').on("click", function () {
        switcher = true;
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var baseElement_map = document.querySelector('div.esri-legend').querySelectorAll('div.esri-legend__layer-caption');
            if (baseElement_map) {
                for (i = 0; i < baseElement_map.length; i++) {
                    layerName = baseElement_map[i].innerHTML;
                    baseElement_map[i].title = tooltipper2(layerName);
                }
            }    
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

My goal is to iterate through each of the 4 items on load (while `i < 4`), match the item title to the title in the `layerNameMapping` object and replace the node item's title with the tt (for 'tooltip'). This works, but only on the first item. After going through the first node item.title ("Modeled Streamline") it breaks when debugging in the console and never moves to the next item. Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: `for (i = 0;` - where do you *think* `i` is defined?  It's not, so it's **global** - and you're using it in both loops.   2nd loop affects first loop.  Change to `for (let i=0...`

Comment: Consider what the output of this would be:  `for (i=0;i<100;++i) { console.log(i); for (i=0;i<100;++i) { } }`  (which is essentially the same as your code)